# How can labels be iteratively added to a GridPane in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, gridpane

I'm trying to iteratively add labels to a GridPane in JavaFX using a for loop, but I keep on getting an error when I try to launch the application. The console output is:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=10.0, vgap=10.0, alignment=TOP_CENTER
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
    at javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.add(GridPane.java:965)
    at com.comsci.drt.ProjectGUI.start(ProjectGUI.java:181)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
```

I'm a beginner in this, but I understand that it's telling me I'm trying to place an object which has already been placed.

**Code:**

```
Label l = new Label();
for(int i = 2; i <= 3; i++) {
    l.setText(finalResultsArray[i].getTeamName());   <-- line 181
    pane1.add(l, 0, i);
}
```

I then proceeded to use an array of labels which I believe wouldn't be trying to replace an object which is already placed, but I receive another error:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.comsci.drt.ProjectGUI.start(ProjectGUI.java:175)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
```

**Code:**

```
Label[] label = new Label[12];
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        label[i].setText(finalResultsArray[i].getTeamName());
        pane1.add(label[i], 0, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a new `Label` instance every time you want to add text to the grid. Furthermore newly created arrays are filled with `null` values.

Possible ways to make this work therefore are

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 3; i++) {
    Label l = new Label();
    l.setText(finalResultsArray[i].getTeamName());
    pane1.add(l, 0, i);
}
```

or

```
Label[] label = new Label[12];
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    label[i] = new Label();
    label[i].setText(finalResultsArray[i].getTeamName());
    pane1.add(label[i], 0, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a constructor for each label. For your first snippet, just move that "new Label" call inside the loop.